# Can JSF converter work with objects of different types which implements the same interface, is it possible?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have different objects which all implements the same interfaces. All of these objects need to be selectable by  `<p:selectCheckboxMenu/>`. **Default** values for those objects and **selected** values are placed in same `Map<?,?>`, and few such `Maps` grouped together inside another `Map`. It sounds complicated but please look at the code below and all will be clear.

When I select an object, converter get a list of all objects from MyBean (CDI bean), looking by `uuid` required object and return it, without throwing any exception. The problem begins when I try to work with selected objects. For example this line of code inside:
`onObjectChange()` method from `MyBean`:

```
List<AllObjects> objects= objectContainer.getControllers().get("Object 1").get("selected");
```

throws an exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with java.util.List
```

And indeed when I hover mouse over `objectContainer` I see that it contains object of type `selected=[Ljava.lang.Object;@dba1b6e7}` But when I evaluate same line of code inside Expressions panel of Eclipse I get the required values: `MyObject1@d8f0f5f8`

I don't understand in general is it possible to do what am I doing, i.e. few different objects with same interface to be selectable by `<p:selectCheckboxMenu/>`. And if yes, why do I have this casting problem? My colleague said that it might be a problem with my `converter` and I tend to agree with she, but don't know is it correct and if yes, how to solve it.

**UPDATE: It looks that problem not inside `Converter` but due to fact that I pass `Collection` to collect selected values dynamically, as a value of `<ui:param/>`. I pass it as `List<AllObjects>` and get it back as `Object`. I can cast it then to `Object[]` and every object inside it to appropriated object by using introspection and it works. But why it mutates initial object? It shouldn't do this.**

Thank you in advance and my code below:

This is an interface:

```
public interfaces AllObjects{
    public String getName();
}
```

There are multiple objects, `MyObject`, `MyObject1`, `MyObject2` which implement interfaces above:

```
public MyObject implements AllObjects{
...
}
```

This is my bean and how my objects are initialized:

```
public MyBean {

    Map<String, Map<String,List<AllObjects>>> objectContainer = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String,List<AllObjects>>>();

    public void init(){

        Map<String,List<AllObjects>> nameValuesPairs1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<AllObjects>>();
        List<AllObjects> allSelectedObjects1 = new ArrayList<AllObjects>();
        List<AllObjects> allDefaultObjects1 = new ArrayList<AllObjects>();
        nameValuesPairs.put("default",allDefaultObjects1);
        nameValuesPairs.put("selected",allSelectedObjects1);

        Map<String,List<AllObjects>> nameValuesPairs2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<AllObjects>>();
        List<AllObjects> allSelectedObjects2 = new ArrayList<AllObjects>();
        List<AllObjects> allDefaultObjects2 = new ArrayList<AllObjects>();
        nameValuesPairs.put("default",allDefaultObjects2);
        nameValuesPairs.put("selected",allSelectedObjects2);

        objectContainer.put("Object 1", nameValuesPairs1);
        objectContainer.put("Object 2", nameValuesPairs2);
    }
    public void onObjectChange(){
        ...
      List<AllObjects> objects= objectContainer .getControllers().get("Object 1").get("selected"); //throws exception
        ...
    }
}
```

My *.xhtml page:

```
<h:panelGroup id="object_panel">

        <ui:repeat id="objects_id" var="object" value="#{myBean.objectContainer.entrySet().toArray()}">

             <p:selectCheckboxMenu 
                            value="#{object.value['selected']}" label="#{object.key}"
                            converter="#{myObjectConverter}" 
                              filter="true" 
                              filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
                              panelStyle="width:250px">
                     <f:selectItems value="#{object.value['default']}" var="value" itemValue="#{value}" itemLabel="#{value.name}" />
                     <p:ajax  event="change" process="@this @parent" listener="#{myBean.onObjectChange}"/>
             </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </ui:repeat>

        </h:panelGroup>
```

And converter:

```
public class ChartParameterConverter implements Converter, Serializable  {

        @Inject
        private MyBean myBean;

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ConverterException {

            AllObjects result = null;
            ...
            //here to result assigned MyObject1 or MyObject2 type depends on condition and it being returned
            ...
            return result;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it looks that `<ui:repeat>` and  `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` not work well with **DataModel** which I used, `Map<String,Map<String,List<MyObject>>>`. I've changed my **DataModel** in the following way:

```
public ObjectContainer{
     private String name;
     private List<MyObject> defaultObjects;
     private List<MyObject> selectedObbjects;
}
```

and pass to `<ui:param>` it as `List<ObjectContainer>`. so my *.xhtml page looks in the following way:

```
         <p:selectCheckboxMenu 
                        value="#{object.selectedObjects}" label="#{object.name}"
                        converter="#{myObjectConverter}" 
                          filter="true" 
                          filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
                          panelStyle="width:250px">
                 <f:selectItems value="#{object.defaultObjects}" var="value" itemValue="#{value}" itemLabel="#{value.name}" />
                 <p:ajax  event="change" process="@this @parent" listener="#{myBean.onObjectChange}"/>
         </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    </ui:repeat>
```

And now everything works as it should.
And I throwed away my custom converter and use `SelectItemsConverter` from [Omnifaces's library](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter). Highly recommended change, code become much simpler and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a unique Tuple for each Object, The Tuple must be converted to unique String.. And you could have the posible values in a Array..

```
static Map<String,Object> uniques = new LinkedHashMap<>();
static{
 //you could save the possible values in a Singleton Bean
 uniques.put(key,value)...
}
```

In your Converter

```
getAsString -> Return a Key from Value
getAsObject -> Return a Value by Key
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how can it help me? I have written in update that it mutate collection which stores values, instead of List I receive Array.

Comment: Your value it should have the way  to obtain your Collection values.. your must have a key String to pass to your html, your html pass the key.. your retrieve the value from the Key. and then.. Your must thinking how to get the array(mutate or Not) using the value or the key.. this is the way of the Converter.

Comment: your value could be a Class to get the mutate values.. class ArrayMutateContainer with properties String getKey() return uniqueString, Collection getMutateValues().. store a Map of ArrayMutateContainer